# Adjusting mouse speed on login screen

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I recently bought a new mouse due to the old one dying, and the new one is quite a bit faster than what I'm used to, causing me to overshoot by a lot whenever I go to click on something. I was able to find out that speed can be adjusted using the 'Mouse' program, which allowed me to resolve my issue for most things, however this only seems to apply when logged into my user account. It doesn't seem to affect things such as the login page or other user accounts. Is there some global setting I can change somewhere that will make this apply to everything?

I am using Windows 7 and an administrator account.

My new mouse is a Logitech M100R corded optical mouse.

The mouse speed was adjusted by going to Control Panel -> Mouse -> Pointer Options -> Motion, then dragging the slider to a lower speed setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mouse settings are stored in the registry at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse
```

The login screen mouse settings are stored at:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Mouse
```

The sensitivity value is named MouseSensitivity.  For only sensitivity, you can create / modify that REG_SZ value.  For all mouse settings, you can export the key (folder) to a .reg file, edit the registry path in Notepad, then import it back in.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: still working 